# How do I read a .csv file in Java with some cells containing multiple lines?

Tags: java, linux, csv

I am trying to read a .csv file in a Java program.  The file has some cells which contain multiple lines.

I am on a linux OS, so I tried removing the line breaks with the following:

awk -v RS="" '{gsub (/\n/,"")}1' cleanPaperAuthor.csv > cleanPaperAuthor1.csv

That DID result in the multi-line data in the cell being displayed all on one line.  But when I attempted to read in the file in java, the reader still thought that it had encountered the end of the line in the middle of the cell data.

So I tried 
awk -v RS="" '{gsub (/\r/,"")}1' cleanPaperAuthor1.csv > cleanPaperAuthor2.csv

That resulted in ALL data in the .csv file being put on one line.

So then I tried 
awk -v RS="" '{gsub (/\r\n/,"")}1' cleanPaperAuthor.csv > cleanPaperAuthor3.csv.

I'm not sure yet if that worked - I am still in the process of opening the file.

I know there is a CSVReader class out there, but I would really like to figure out what I can do without having to deal with getting that set up and changing my code.  Anyone out there have any ideas?  I'm completely befuddled at this point.

Comment: Why are you fiddling with awk if you intend to use java?

Comment: Because I don't know of an easy way to get the file fixed.  I need the multiple-line cells changed to be single-line with no <CR> in them.  The .csv files are too large to open and edit - something like 617,000 bytes.  If there's an easy way to do this in Java, I'm all for it.

Comment: The problem is I'm not sure what your .csv file looks like.  If cells can have newlines then what terminates a row?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea.  I tried to open this up in Wordpad to edit it and get rid of the multi-line cells, but my application froze because the file was so big.

Comment: Actually I just crawled through the OpenCSV source Ravi is pointing you at.  The trick is quotes.  As long as your cells are not only comma separated  but in quotes then the new lines in cells are only for the cell not for the line.  If your cells are quoted then OpenCVS should do you fine.

Comment: Tried downloading a CSVReader I found the other day by Steven Ostermiller. Unfortunately, that didn't help.  I opened the file in Wordpad and was actually able to find the line that has been giving me trouble - the field with newlines is enclosed in double quotation marks.  I'm going to see if OpenCSV works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a CSV parser is extremely easy; both the setup and the API. And, in addition to handling the values that span multiple lines it can take care of things like commas in quoted elements and parsing just the values inside the quotes `""` etc. for you. Plus, you can use the library to serialize your text back to CSV as well.

Here's an example with [OpenCSV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/) to read a line of csv values.

```
    String input = "value1, \"value2\", \"value3, 1234\", \"value4\n"
            + "value5\n"
            + "value6\"";

    try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(input))) {
        String [] tokens;
        while ((tokens = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

***Output :*** *("value3, 1234" is one value.)*

```
[value1, value2, value3, 1234, value4
value5
value6]
```

Just make sure to add [Apache Commons Lang 3.x](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) jar to your *classpath*.

Comment: Thanks, Ravi.  I have pulled in OpenCSV - however, it didn't fix my problem.  Problem is now solved, though.  As I read in each string, I remove any/all \n characters from the string.  Not sure what the problem was before, my guess is that I may have inadvertently changed the file so that it wasn't being read as a true .csv file.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect one of your `awk` commands have substituted *newlines* with the literal string `"\n"` i.e. two characters `'\'` and `'n'`. My solution would have worked otherwise. But, good to know you've got it sorted :)

Comment: I was trying to parse csv generated from SO/SEDE table, does not solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
        String UPLOADED_FOLDER = "/home/Rahul/Developement/Rahul/personal/uploadedfile/";
        try {

            // ** get the file and store at to that location **

            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            Path path = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + file.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(path, bytes);

            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("You successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();

            System.out.println("/home/Rahul/Developement/Rahul/personal/uploadedfile/" + fileName);

            String filePath = new File("/home/Rahul/Developement/Rahul/personal/uploadedfile/")
                    .getAbsolutePath();

            boolean check = true;

            File file1 = new File("/home/Rahul/Developement/Rahul/personal/uploadedfile/" + fileName);

            System.out.println(file1.exists());

            // TO CHECK FILE IS CSV OR NOT
            if (fileName.endsWith(".csv")) {

                check = true;

                System.out.println("extension");

                if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {

                    // *** to read the file from the location
                    // **("/home/Rahul/Developement/Rahul/personal/uploadedfile/")**

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                            "/home/Rahul/Developement/Rahul/personal/uploadedfile/" + fileName));

                    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(
                            "/home/Rahul/Developement/Rahul/personal/uploadedfile/" + fileName);
}
```